# Jpa validation include field name into the message

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, jpa

Is there an easy generic way to include the field name into the error message for JPA validation?

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[a-z ]+", message = "The field: FIELD contains invalid characters: ${validatedValue}") 
private String text;
```

some might say "just type the name of the field"... please if you dont know dont say, but dont suggest something that stupid... if it was only one field i would certainly do that... but is a system with hundreds of fields... some of them might change the names in the future... i would like to have a proper way to get the information...

it is possible to get the field value with ${validatedValue} so maybe there is a way to get the field name

Comment: I'll be the other smart person that says, don't include the name in the message ;) Seriously though, can't you append the field name from a constraint violation exception into a custom message format and publish that error message instead? `jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolation#getPropertyPath` gives you all you need.